# Uploads Getting Corrupted But File Size is Correct?

Tags: .net, powershell, png

I'm using Invoke-Restmethod to try upload a png file to rapidshare, the filesize on the server is correct but if I download the file it's not even an image, this is definitely   an encoding issue but I have no clue what I'm doing wrong?

```
$FreeUploadServer = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=nextuploadserver"
$url = "http://rs$FreeUploadServer.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi"
$fields = @{sub='upload';login='username';password='pass';filename='2he1re.png';filecontent=$(Get-Content C:\libs\test.png -Raw)}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Body $fields -Method Post -ContentType "image/png"
```

I have tried all kinds of stuff, anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Reading the file content using the `-Raw` parameter is still returning a `string` object and this is probably going to be problematic for a binary file like a PNG.  I think the RapidShare API is expecting URL-encoded form post data.  Try this:

```
## !! It would be nice if this worked, but it does not - see update below !!
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$fields = @{sub='upload';login='username';password='pass';filename='2he1re.png';
            filecontent=Get-Content C:\libs\test.png -Enc Byte -Raw}
```

BTW I think you might want to ditch setting the `ContentType`.  The content type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - I think.

I found [this post](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/encoding_forms) useful on the difference between HtmlEncode and UrlEncode.

**Update:** it appears the `Invoke-RestMethod` is URL encoding the body for a POST when the body is in the form of a hashtable. That's nice. However it doesn't appear to accept byte arrays.  It is expecting every value in the hashtable to be a string or representable as a string i.e. it invokes ToString() on each value.  This makes it challenging to get the binary data encoded properly.  I have question into the PowerShell team on this.

OK, figured out a reasonable workaround.  Remember how I mentioned before, that passing the Body as a string was the equivalent to passing in a hashtable?  Well, turns out there is one important difference. :-) When you pass in a string, the cmdlet doesn't Url encode it. So if we pass in a string, we can bypass what I consider to be a limitation of this cmdlet (not supporting byte[] values in a hashtable).  Try this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$png  = [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode((Get-Content C:\libs\test.png -Enc Byte -Raw))
$body = "sub=upload&login=username&password=pass&filename=2he1re.png&filecontent=$png"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Body $body -Method Post
```

Comment: thanks Keith, will give this a shot later, would this be just for this cmdlet or do hash tables not support byte arrays in general ?

Comment: This is just for hashtables passed to the Body parameter of the Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet.

Comment: You sir, are a genius. :D it works! THANKS! Also why do they do this with hash tables in the Body? Is there a reason, im relatively new to powershell and im trying to learn as much as i can ?

Comment: i thought it worked :( Keith would you have any idea as to why this only works on small files ? If i try upload a file larger than 1MB it errors, i spoke to someone and they said the URL could be too long, any ideas ?

Comment: The max size of the URL encoded data would be controlled by RapidShare's web server. Apparently in can range from 128KB to 2GB.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string For large files, you may have to use RapidShare's sub=uploadresume functionality - breaking the file up into chunks.